# Duplicate the dropdown with UI and the selected value using Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, sass

I am having a drop-down with the options in it and also having a button. If I select any one of the options from drop-down and click the button means I want the copy of that drop-down to be display below. i.e) the drop-down want to display the selected option as a default Label.

**So, at-last i will be seeing the two drop-downs. How can i solve this using Angular ?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check this sample I created,
[Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-htapmp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

HTML Content

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"> 
  <option  *ngFor = "let option of options" [value]="option" >{{option}}</option>
</select>
<button (click)="onBtnClick()">Click Me</button>

<div>
<select *ngFor = "let dOption of duplicateOptions" [(ngModel)]="selectedDuplicatedOption">
  <option  *ngFor = "let option of options" [value]="option" >{{option}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Javascript Content

```html
export class AppComponent  {

  options: any = ['One','Two','Three'];
  selectedOption: string;
  selectedDuplicatedOption: string;
  duplicateOptions: any = [];

  onBtnClick(){
    this.duplicateOptions.push(this.selectedOption);
    this.selectedDuplicatedOption = this.selectedOption;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I hope this helps. But for me having only one <select> , there will be dynamically renders based on the options in it. Here, hardcoded as two drop-downs.

Comment: In your above example, try creating copy : 1st Dropdown to 2nd dropdown, and in second dropdown click any one of the option and click the button , it will create the another DD. Now changing the values in second dropdown. You will see the values are also changing in the third dropdown too.